# How to create layout on button click

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, layout

I want to create a new layout when clicking on a button, and use some script to make this new layout exactly like a pre-existing layout in a xml file.
My problem is not to create the base layout but to make it look like the "resource" layout.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: u mean u want to create dynamic layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding content to a linear layout dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661261/adding-content-to-a-linear-layout-dynamically)

Comment: uuh yeah it seems to be a Dynamic Layout I want to make, but I'd like to create a new Layout (with `Layout layout = new Layout()` I suppose) and making it like a layout already existing in a .xml file, but I don't know how to do

Answer (score -1):

Try to consider [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

A good starting point is a standard project "File>New Project>.
In the add activity tab, select tabbed Activity.

You'll find many posts on stackoverflow on [that subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827072/why-use-fragments/14912608).

Comment: he want to create dynamic layout not fragments

Comment: Yes, @Ashvinsolanki I've read the question. I'm just suggesting fragment as the snippet built by the project wizard gives an elegant answer.  I guess this is leading to the same result + giving the ability to the user to navigate through "Inventories"